# quickest way to change set of var values

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a bunch of variables that the values of are taken from a DB.  They're boolean values of 'true' or 'false'.  What is the easiest way to change all of the variables that hold a 'true' value to a string value of say, 'yes', and all of the variable with a value of 'false' would be changed to 'no'?

Comment: It all depends on how your data is stored.  If you have a bunch of named variables, it'll be much more difficult than if they're stored in an array or object.  Can you provide more information?

Comment: They are in an array but some of them are neither 'false' nor 'true' but already string values, does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = myArray[i]? "yes" : "no";
}
```